# How to tag content from external databases?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, database

I have an external database with a couple of hundred rows and columns. Is there a way in which I can tag content while or after I import the database to my drupal 7 website? Is there any module already contributed which could be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

by tagging you mean reference taxonomy terms ?

you could import those rows with the [migrate module](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) as nodes, with taxonomy reference (a normal taxonomy field), into your drupal DB.

Comment: the database has a couple of tables but they are not tagged right now. they are just normal database tables. i want to tag them along with migrating them to my drupal DB or just using them externally. But I am not sure how to tag the database if I don't migrate it.

Comment: what do you mean by tag ? / what does the external data represent ?

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply. the purpose for using tag is that I want to implement search functionality that would use these tags to look/search for relevant data and display the fields/rows/columns accordingly. i do not have taxonomy reference right now. the basic way in which I would want to go about the process is (I am not sure if that can be done or not): import the external database into my Drupal 7 website as either custom content types or as a database alone, use content tagging to facilitate search and perform search functionality and have different views for every search criteria.

Comment: drupal search will include everything of the nodes. so i suggest (again) to import your data as nodes (with a special content type), using the migrate module. additionally you can setup a taxonomy vocabulary handling your tags, and add this vocabulary to the new content type. while importing; you can add 'tags' to the newly created nodes.